# Core Data или странная ошибка: A section returned nil value for section name key path

Tags: xcode, objective-c, coredata

Всем привет! Вопрос для знатоков Core Data:
Имеем базу (не принципиально), в которой 2 таблицы связанных меж собою Relationship.

Так вот вопрос: Когда я делаю запрос NSFetchedResultsController в Table1:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

//sortDescription
NSMutableArray *sortDescriptors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortDescriptor];
if (sectionName) {
    NSSortDescriptor *tempDescript = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sectionName ascending:YES];
    [sortDescriptors insertObject:tempDescript atIndex:0];
}
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:sectionName cacheName:entityName];
```

sectionName = "relToTable2", то есть хочу сделать разделение на секции по объектам во второй таблице.

Все работает и все замечательно, но вот незадача: relToTable2 - не обязательная связь и ее может не быть между объектами. И конечно же CoreData радостно выдает (если есть объекты без связи со второй таблицей):

> CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) A section returned nil value for section name key path 'relToTable2'. Objects will be placed in unnamed section

Вот тут вопрос: ЭТО критично? Само приложение не "падает", секцию успешно создает. Просто неприятно когда в логах ошибки.

***Update 1*** 
Станислав, СПАСИБО!
Сама заметка хорошая, подобное я смотрел вчера и проблема этого решения опять же в том, что там Всегда есть данные и CoreData просто не реагирует. НО Спасибо за идею. Статья натолкнула меня на мысль и она сработала:
В самом классе объекта Table1 я создаю "переменную":

```
.h
@interface Table1 : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * tableDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * tableNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Table2 *relToTable2;
-(NSString *)sectionName;

.m
-(NSString *)sectionName {
return (self.relToTable2) ? self.relToTable2.Name : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No-Name"];
```

}

Сам Fetch меняем:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

//sortDescription
NSSortDescriptor *tempDescript = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"relToTable2" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[tempDescript, nil]];
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:entityName];
```

Вот и все: Секция (даже нулевая) имеет свое имя, CoreData не ругается!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это явно критично. А какое значение в вашем sectionName? Видели вот это?

Comment: Станислав, СПАСИБО!

Сама заметка зорошая, подобное я смотрел вчера и проблема этого решения опять же в том, что там Всегда есть данные и CoreData просто не реагирует.
НО Спасибо за идею. Статья натолкнула меня на мысль и она сработала:

Смотрите Udate1